# Store the indices of the selected variables of a listbox in a list

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I would like to save in an "indice" list all the indexes of the variables selected in the listbox. Any solution? At the moment I select a variable and it returns its index to me. I am not able to select multiple variables and save all indices in a list.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import RIGHT, VERTICAL, Y

Ch_Output = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Seleziona canale')
root.geometry("400x500")

var_select = str()
indice = int()

def getElement(event):  
 selection = event.widget.curselection()
 index = selection[0]
 value = event.widget.get(index)

 result.set(value)
 print('\n',index,' -> ',value)
 global var_select
 global indice
 var_select = value
 indice = index
 #root.destroy()

# scroll bar-------

result =tk.StringVar()
my_frame = tk.Frame(root)
my_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(my_frame, orient=VERTICAL)

var2 = tk.StringVar()
var2.set(Ch_Output)

# list box-----------
my_listbox = tk.Listbox(my_frame, width=50, height=20, listvariable=var2)

# configure scrolbar
my_scrollbar.config(command=my_listbox.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
my_frame.pack()

my_listbox.pack(pady=15)

my_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', getElement) #Select click

root.mainloop()

print('\n',indice)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you can select only one item. If you want to select multiple items at once you need to specify `selectmode` to `tk.MULTIPLE` or `tk.EXTENDED`.

In your case:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import RIGHT, VERTICAL, Y, MULTIPLE

...

selected_index = []
def getElement(event):  
     global selected_index
     selected_index = list(event.widget.curselection())
     print(selected_index)
     print("Values: ", [event.widget.get(x) for x in selected_index])
...
my_listbox = tk.Listbox(my_frame, width=50, height=20, listvariable=var2, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
...
root.mainloop()
```